# A wonky return statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

The following function works and does its intended job - returns the desired value as specified.

```
function returnValue() {
    return( 
          "value");
}
```

Just the return value is split into a new line.

---

If the pair of parentheses is dropped as follows then, it returns `undefined`.

```
function returnValue() {
    return 
         "value";
}
```

The IDE I'm using issues a warning as follows.

> Code has no side effects

It seems like "value" is not part of the `return` statement itself.

Why do they both behave differently?

Comment: @Shai: Similar, but quite obviously not a duplicate.

Comment: Related: [What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/2074608)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in Javascript, a statement can be terminated by a newline *instead* of a semicolon. The semicolon is essentially inserted automatically, *but only where the result can be a full statement*.

`return;` is valid on its own, but then your function returns nothing and your `"value";` has no side-effects.

On the other hand, your first example simply cannot be parsed this way because the line ends in the middle of a parenthesis.

These rules are described in §7.9.1 in the ECMA-262 standard document.

Answer (score 3):

Automatic Semicolon Insertion is the cause. When the expression to return starts on a separate line to the `return` keyword, a semicolon is inserted after the `return` statement. Semicolons are optional in many cases but this is not one of them

So

```
function returnValue() {
    return 
         "value";
}
```

ends up becoming/being interpreted as

```
function returnValue() {
    return; // <- semicolon inserted here
         "value";
}
```

which results in `undefined` being returned. One way to fix this is to start the value to return on the same line as `return`.

There are **[rules for when automatic semicolon insertion](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9)** happens, summarized as

> The resulting practical advice to ECMAScript programmers is:
>
> 1. A postfix ++ or -- operator should appear on the same line as its operand.
> 2. An Expression in a return or throw statement should start on the same line as the return or throw token.
> 3. A label in a break or continue statement should be on the same line as the break or continue token.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript automatically inserts a semicolon after `return`.

Read more: [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Answer (score 2):

That's because JavaScript automatically adds a semicolon to the end of the return line, so in the second example, it's essentially as if it said just `return;`.